# Linkable book page on the web

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

**Problem**:

Imagine a book page, any page (an example is provided below), that only contains text (without paragraphs, images, indents etc.) The page is composed of multiple sentences, each sentence separated by a period. Any given sentence can start and end on the same line or stretch two or multiple lines.

It is given that each page:

1. Has a fixed width (and height) and
2. The text is justified.

**Question:**

If we now want to make a web page in HTML/CSS representing the physical book page, with roughly identical width/(height) / but fixed(!), justified text and line breaks, while at the same time not depending too much on any given font for the alignment AND making each sentence linkable, how is this best archived?

**Example:**

[Web book page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIVkh.jpg), where the underlined 'red' should represent a `<a>` link and 'green' another link etc.

**Considerations:**

Ideally we would use `flex`, `flex-direction: row;` with `justify-content: space-between;` for each sentence, but then we can't make sentences linkable across multiple rows.

Note: Using good old `inline` and `text-align: justify;` don't give us control of the exact line breaks (without depending on a specific font-width way too much), and the old [hack](https://kristinlbradley.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/cross-browser-css-justify-last-line-paragraph-text/) for 'All Justified Text' only works for the last line (or else we would end up having crossing `<span>` and `<a>` to handle the line breaks and linkable text).